# Hotkey to restart autohotkey script?

Tags: autohotkey

Say I have an autohotkey script `C:\path\to\my\script` running. Is there a way to define a hotkey that re-starts it?

Comment: Related: [Automatically reload AutoHotkey script when modified](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45468335/3357935)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In order to prevent duplicate instances, I normally do not re-launch a script but use the build-in function [Reload](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Reload.htm). I launch this with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to edit the main AHK script.

```
^#!r::Reload
```

Actually, my script looks like this:

```
^#!r::
Send, ^s ; To save a changed script
Sleep, 300 ; give it time to save the script
Reload
Return

^!#e::Edit
```

As a matter of fact, all the way at the top of my script I have this to give me a visual and audio indication that the script was restarted:

```
#SingleInstance Force
#installKeybdHook
#Persistent
Menu, Tray, Icon , Shell32.dll, 25, 1
TrayTip, AutoHotKey, Started, 1
SoundBeep, 300, 150
Return
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a hotkey that runs a script, which in this case is the same script and  then exit.

```
somehotkey::
    Run, C:\path\to\my\script.ahk
    ExitApp
return
```

Comment: In order to prevent multiple instances running at the same time (run creates a new instance), I use `^#!r::Reload`

Comment: @RobertIlbrink. If that restarts the script, you should post that as an answer. Your solution may be better than Armin's if it avoids intance duplicates.

Comment: @RobertIlbrink Reload does exactly the same thing as my suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Restart the AutoHotkey script with a hotkey.
Autohotkey 2.0 version:

```
#r:: ; press control+r to reload
{ 
  msgResult := MsgBox("Do you really want to reload this script?")
  if (msgResult = "Yes")
    Reload()
  return
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I found this to be the safest option of them all, because it takes care that the correct script is reloaded when you have multiple scripts running simultaneously, which was a recurring issue for me. The combination of the following also ensures that only one instance of a script will ever run at a time. The ScriptFullPath variable includes the name of the script.

```
#SingleInstance Force ;put this at the top of the script
^r::run, %A_ScriptFullPath%
```