# Automatically reload AutoHotkey script when modified

Tags: autohotkey

When testing AutoHotkey scripts, I sometimes forget to reload my scripts after making changes. This leads to me accidentally testing old, outdated versions of my scripts.

Instead of manually reloading the script, I would like to have scripts automatically reload if they have been modified.

**How can I make AutoHotkey reload the current script any time a `.ahk` file is modified?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Somewhere near start of the script, in the [auto-execute section](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#auto)

```
#SingleInstance force
FileGetTime ScriptStartModTime, %A_ScriptFullPath%
SetTimer CheckScriptUpdate, 100, 0x7FFFFFFF ; 100 ms, highest priority
```

Anywhere in the script (usually somewhere at the bottom):

```
CheckScriptUpdate() {
    global ScriptStartModTime
    FileGetTime curModTime, %A_ScriptFullPath%
    If (curModTime == ScriptStartModTime)
        return
    SetTimer CheckScriptUpdate, Off
    Loop
    {
        reload
        Sleep 300 ; ms
        MsgBox 0x2, %A_ScriptName%, Reload failed. ; 0x2 = Abort/Retry/Ignore
        IfMsgBox Abort
            ExitApp
        IfMsgBox Ignore
            break
    } ; loops reload on "Retry"
}
```

Comment: @StevenVascellaro nope, check builtin variables here: https://autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#prop

Comment: After adding this script, my AHK file is sometimes reloaded as two duplicate instances which run simultaneously

Comment: @StevenVascellaro strange, because reload command should have prevented that. Tried adding `#SingleInstance force` to start of the script? Also I edited the script to detect the condition.

Comment: @StevenVascellaro also, I added highest priority to start of the procedure to avoid another reload or restart while one is already queued

Comment: I found the script was less susceptible to errors when I changed `Sleep 100` to `Sleep 200`

Comment: hm, ok. Example in the manual uses 1000 ms delay, but that's too long to my taste.

Comment: a warning pops up saying that the `ScriptStartModTime` variable (in the line `If (curModTime <> ScriptStartModTime) {`) has not been assigned a value

Comment: @Ooker have you added `FileGetTime ScriptStartModTime, %A_ScriptFullPath%` before `SetTimer`? It seeds the value.

Comment: @Ooker strange, I have no idea why. Probably missing some details. I suggest you ask separate question, you may post a link here.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I've done it:

```
#If WinActive("AHK.ahk - Notepad") or WinActive("*AHK.ahk - Notepad")
    ~^s::
        Reload
    Return
#If
```

Checks if the current window is the script that I want autoreloaded whenever I hit Ctrl-S. 
 The `~` means the default action of Ctrl-S (saving the file) is preserved, and then we simply reload it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still new at AHK but here's what I've come with.
If you're using Notepad++ to edit AHKS this will run any ahk that's  open and currently in focus in Notepad++ on saving with Ctrl-S and won't effect any other file types.

This script only has to be in one running ahk to work on all ahks being modified in Notepad++.

This can be used on multiple text editor programs too like win Notepad just get rid of the ++ associated with Notepad++

```
    ~^s:: ; Saves and Runs ANY AHK open in Notepad++
    Sleep 150
    WinGetTitle, Title, A
    Needle := "ahk - Notepad++"
    IfInString, Title, %Needle%
     {  
     StringReplace, xxx, Title,- Notepad++, , All
      run %xxx% 
     return                         
     }      
    else
    return
```

Answer (score 0):

```
~^s::
    WinGetTitle, currentTitle, A
    if InStr(currentTitle, ".ahk")
    {
        Send, {Ctrl Down}s{Ctrl Up}
        Sleep, 300
        StringReplace, fileName, currentTitle, .ahk*, , All
        StringReplace, fileName, fileName, .ahk, , All
        filePath := "C:\Autohotkey\" . fileName . ".ahk"
        Run, %filePath%
    }
return
```

Replace `C:\Autohotkey\` with the path you put your autohotkey scripts in